# StarCraft2: pricing and subscription policy

Tags: starcraft-2

One of the Russian-language websites that is selling SC2 has 2 buying options:

1. 12 month subscription - costs around $35
2. additional 4 month subscription - costs around $17-$18

http://www.ozon.ru/?context=search&group=pcgame&text=starcraft+2

I bought SC2 from Battle.net and don't remember what I bought, actually (it cost $60).

Is there any subscription limitation for SC2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starcraft 2 does indeed require a subscription... [in Russia](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/99929-StarCraft-II-Will-Have-Monthly-Fees-But-Only-In-Russia).

The pricing for Starcraft 2 changes from region to region and one of the differences between here and Moscow is that there you pay a subscription for Starcraft 2.

Its important to note that you can still buy a Full EU edition (in Russia) without a subscription and get along just fine.  You are not forced to pay subscription.

Comment: The article mentions that one can also buy the standard full price version without subscription in Russia. So if the OP already owns it he does not have to pay any more (if the article is accurate).

Comment: @Fabian yes, but that is a separate edition.  If you bought subscription you have to pay subscription.

Answer (score 6):

There are two (general) pricing options in Russia - either buy the full game (60$ "European" version) and play for an unlimited time, or buy a cheaper but time-limited version of the game. **If you already bought the full version, there's no point buying any of the subscription-based versions**, you don't lose anything - there's no extra bonus from the subscription, you're either able to play the game or you don't.

Notice the subscription is only about playing online - the single-player game isn't time-limited.

See more information [here](http://www.sc2blog.com/2010/04/14/monthly-fee-for-starcraft-2-officially-confirmed-in-russia/).